# How can I change CMYK and Registration colors to RGB in Scribus?

Tags: inkscape, cmyk, color-conversion, rgb, scribus

I need to convert all of my file's colors to RGB.

Most of them are already RGB. There are 2 CMYK and 1 Registration.

I can edit the RGB colors into CMYK with the `Edit` button, but not the other way around.
[image]

Any idea how I can do this in Scribus? Or do I need another program to do it?

Comment: Did you actually use the 'color' Registration for anything? It has a *very* specific use in CMYK printing, but for RGB use you should simply use black.

Answer (score 1):

*Registration Black*, (*CMYK Black*), and *CMYK White* are protected colors in Scribus.

Personally, I think that this *limitation* should be removed, but I'm not sure that it will ever happen.

For now, you can just ignore those colors: if you don't use them they will not affect your exported document.